# Make a UIElement's width auto but not autofit to its parent?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, blend

Does anyone know how to make a UIElement's width auto but not autofit to its parent? I want it to expand past the container (even if it's cut off.)

Right now it does this:
[image]

I want it to do this:
[image]

I am able to achieve this if I define the width in xaml but I'd like to do it with auto.

Xaml:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ItemTemplate">
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding RandomValues}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate x:Key="UniformGridPanel">
        <UniformGrid Rows="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>

<ListBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="Auto" DataContext="{Binding}" ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource ItemTemplate}" ItemsSource="{Binding Collection}" ItemsPanel="{DynamicResource UniformGridPanel}" Style="{DynamicResource ListBoxStyle}"/>
```

Comment: What's in your `ListboxStyle`? Without specific style and `Width="Auto"`, the `ListBox` expand to its content only, disregarding its container. But the `Style` can overwrite this.

Comment: Sorry I can't check right now. I generated the style from default but I'm pretty sure I didn't do anything to it. Do you have any suggestions on what I can edit in the style?

Comment: You should remove everything that is related to the size behavior. In most cases, when you define a style, you should specify only the things that are different from the original one. Otherwise you may be confused with some unattended overwriting.